# Markdown rendered incorrectly with npm-markdown

Tags: node.js, markdown

I am using nodejs-markdown from here:
https://npmjs.org/package/markdown
But the stuff between "---" in the headers is not getting rendered - only horizontal lines are created

Why does this occur? Does this automatically convert the stuff into some kind of meta-data?

```
---
layout: post    
title: Just another post
something: more
this
and that
and more of that
---

About Me
--------
I'm a programmer
```

I am using nodejs-markdown from here:
https://npmjs.org/package/markdown
But the stuff between "---" in the headers is not getting rendered - only horizontal lines are created

Why does this occur? Does this automatically convert the stuff into some kind of meta-data?

EDIT:
Input to npm-Markdown is:

```
var content = fs.readFileSync(filepath,'utf8');
var htmlContent = markdown.toHTML(content);
```

Output is as shown below - with nothing rendered between the hr's:

```
<hr/>
<hr/>
<h2>About Me</h2>
<p>I&#39;m a programmer</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: It **is** a programming question - its okay if you don't have an answer or need additional info - why downgrade the question

Comment: just added more info to this question.

Comment: You've improved it so I'll withdraw the down vote.